# What is the best way to create an account and fund it with some cpu / net / ram via the command line?

Tags: accounts, command-line

I'm looking to create a php script that can communicate with the EOS blockchain to be able to setup an account and then fund it with some ram/cpu/net. What tools do I need on my web server to make this happen? I'm basically trying to build out something like: https://namevault.co

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need should be [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-create-account), however you will need to install cleos on the machine first. This is a command line utility, I'm unaware of any native php eos libraries.

Comment: Yes, I know that is to create an account. But how do you create an account and also fund the account with some eos and stake it and send it some ram with just ONE command? Or do you need multiple commands?